# how to convert english date to arabic date ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, calendar, arabic

[image]in my app i am getting date in this format = "2016-02-15 10:49:59" bu i want to display it in this format "الأربعاء, 9 مارس, 2016 10:33 ص" so how can i do this?

i mage showing the format in which i want iot

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make use of `NSDateFormatter` and locale `"ar_DZ"`, with a custom format specification to fit your needs: `"EEEE, d, MMMM, yyyy HH:mm a"`.

```
// input date in given format (as string)
let inputDateAsString = "2016-03-09 10:33:59"

// initialize formatter and set input date format
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

// read input date string as NSDate instance
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(inputDateAsString) {

    // set locale to "ar_DZ" and format as per your specifications
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_DZ")
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d, MMMM, yyyy HH:mm a"
    let outputDate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

    print(outputDate) // الأربعاء, 9 مارس, 2016 10:33 ص
}
```

Note that the above uses the default gregorian calendar (in so not translating e.g. year 2016 to year 1437  (/1438 ~October 2016) in the islamic calendar).

---

*(Edit addition regarding your comment below)*

If you change `localeIdentifier` above from `"ar_DZ"` to `"ar"`, also numeric values gets written in arabic characters:

```
print(outputDate) // الأربعاء, ٩ مارس, ٢٠١٦ ١٠:٣٣ ص
```

However, I don't know arabic, so I can't really say if your image above displays that, and I'm no longer certain what you're trying to achieve; possibly this is not it.

Comment: thanks @dfri its working for me but actually i also want all digit in arabic. i edit my question please review it

Comment: @GovindRakholiya Happy to help. To whomever downvoted this answer: possibly give me feedback and I might learn something/improve the answer (rather than just shooting off a drive-by downvote).

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
let morningOfChristmasComponents = NSDateComponents()
        morningOfChristmasComponents.year = 2014
        morningOfChristmasComponents.month = 12
        morningOfChristmasComponents.day = 25
        morningOfChristmasComponents.hour = 7
        morningOfChristmasComponents.minute = 0
        morningOfChristmasComponents.second = 0

        let morningOfChristmas = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(morningOfChristmasComponents)!


        /***** NSDateFormatter Part *****/

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar")

        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(morningOfChristmas)
        txtMarks.text = dateString
```

Answer (score 5):

For solving of youre issue try to use legend way with NSCalendar style:

```
var today = NSDate()
let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil)!
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
formatter.calendar = islamic
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_DZ")
formatter.stringFromDate(today) // "30 جمادى الأولى، 1437 هـ، 11:22:10 ص"
```

To configure proper style set yore's `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` also set up youre `NSLocale`.